# How to setup redis as cache with flask-session when working with containers?

Tags: docker, flask, redis, docker-network

I'm trying to deploy a flaskapp with docker, so I have two containers, one for my flaskapp and another for redis. I've setup a network and executed both within it. When accessing my flaskapp the following error occurs:

> ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.

This is happening because I'm using redis as cache for flask-session and I'm hosting redis at a container called exampleredis.

My question is: how can I setup redis host to be exampleredis in Flask?

I have the following config file:

```
class DevConfig(Config):
    REDIS_HOST = 'exampleredis'
    SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
    JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR = False
    JSON_SORT_KEYS = False
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 15
    DEBUG = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [document of `flask-session`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/#configuration), this should probably work:

```py
import redis

class DevConfig(Config):
    SESSION_REDIS = redis.from_url('redis://exampleredis:6379')
    SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
    ...
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! It is partially correct, because as stated in the redis source code documentation, the url provided must begin with redis://(for normal TCP socket connection), rediss://(for SSL wrapped TCP socket connection) or unix://(a Unix Domain Socket connection). So in my case, it should be: `redis.from_url('redis://exampleredis:6379')`